# Return two JSON objects to AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, json

I make an AJAX request to a PHP file as follows:

```js
function verifica() {
  var meuid = $('.meuid').attr('id');
  var datas = "user=" + meuid;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'sys/stream2.php',
    data: datas
  }).done(function(data) {
    //alert(data);
    $('#nome').html(data);
  });
}
```

In my PHP file, I output JSON data from a loop:

```php
foreach ($gUsuarios as $usuarios) {
  $agora = $usuarios['AGORA'];   
  if ($agora >= $usuarios['cUsu_Limite']) {            
    echo json_encode(array('usuarioon' => $usuarios['cUsu_ID'], 'status' => 'fa fa-circle-o text-red'));            
  } else {    
    echo json_encode(array('usuarioon' => $usuarios['cUsu_ID'], 'status' => 'fa fa-circle-o text-green'));
  }
}
```

The output is two JSON objects:

```json
{"usuarioon":"1","status":"fa fa-circle-o text-red"}
{"usuarioon":"3","status":"fa fa-circle-o text-red"}
```

How can I parse the two JSON objects in my AJAX success handler? I've tried with `parseJSON`, but it did not work. I think it's because I'm returning an array within a `foreach`.

Comment: You can't send two json objects to the ajax request, you should make another array and add both json objects on it, then encode this one array as json.

Comment: Can you explain better? @PhiterFernandes

Comment: I made an answer, check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't echo multiple json strings into your Ajax request, that will make it fail.

If you do this, you will get the desired results:

```
$retorno = array();
foreach ($gUsuarios as $usuarios) {
  $agora = $usuarios['AGORA'];   
  if ($agora >= $usuarios['cUsu_Limite']) {            
    $retorno[] = json_encode(array('usuarioon' => $usuarios['cUsu_ID'], 'status' => 'fa fa-circle-o text-red'));            
  } else {    
    $retorno[] = json_encode(array('usuarioon' => $usuarios['cUsu_ID'], 'status' => 'fa fa-circle-o text-green'));
  }
}
echo json_encode($retorno);
```

Comment: Ok , no data Have To Put my answer data[x ] . As I walk THAT data agora ... To Set the User class and to assign ?

Comment: I'm doing well ,
alert ( data [0 ] ) ;
and it returns me :
{ " Usuarioon " , " 1", " status " : " fa -circle - text- red" }
Okay, here.
How could I do this:
$ ( '#' + Data [0 ] .usuarioon . ) .addClass ( Data.[0]status ) ;

@PhiterFernandes ???